# ¿Como puedo calcular una media aritmetica en mi codigo?

Tags: java, array, netbeans, math

Me piden calcular la media de un arreglo con numeros entre 10,000 y 999999 numeros, dentro de los cuales solo debo generar mil, busque en algunas fuentes el codigo solo que en cada una es diferente y se me dificulta entenderlo, me podrian dar una mano, porfavor

import java.util.Random;

public class Trabj_1 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random aleatorio = new Random();
    int ent;
    int num [][];
    num = new int [0][999];
    for (int i=0; i<999; i++){
        ent = aleatorio.nextInt(10000,999999);
        System.out.println("No. aleatorio: " + ent);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: matematicas.. vamos.. como se calcula la media de cualquier cosa????

Comment: *"busque en algunas fuentes el codigo"* -> Y si en vez de buscar de dónde puedas copiarlo intentas hacerlo? La parte complicada ya la hiciste, en realidad.

Comment: Ese es el problema, no me han enseñado a como hacerlo en codigo y no logro entender los ejemplos de google

Comment: Buenas, Diego, pero si te lo hacemos nosotros, ¿cómo aprendes? El día del examen no vamos a estar ahí. Tienes que: 1) declarar un arreglo de 1000 enteros (Esa parte ya la tienes mal, no necesitas dos indices, sino uno), 2) almacenar en dicho arreglo 1000 números aleatorios y luego calcular la media (que es la suma de todos los números divida por 1000, que es el número de elementos, una media matemática, como te decía gbianchi)

Comment: No tenés que buscar código. Tenés que saber calcular la media aritmética (sí, matemáticas), y luego _intentar plasmarlo en código_. Si de ahí tenés problemas o algún error en particular, es otra cosa. No todo es código y ya: primero es la lógica.

Comment: Pude hacerlo con un for, le batalle un poco para que me corriera, ya que tenia que agregar mas cosas, pero pude, gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer todo el proceso sin tener que utilizar bucles:

```java
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.OptionalDouble;

public class Trabj_1 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random aleatorio = new Random();
    // El primer parametro es del método .ints el numero de enteros a crear, 
    // el segundo parametro es el mínimo y el tercero el máximo
    OptionalDouble resultado = random.ints(1000, 10000, 99999).average();
    System.out.println("La media es: " + resultado.toString());
  }

}
```